# Finding Pareto distribution's Kurtosis

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, kurtosis, pareto-distribution

I have no clue how to solve this question:

---

**Questions**:
Given that each of a,b,c,d and e is a digit from {0,1,2,3,...,9} and f is an alphabet from {A,B,C,D,...,Z}

X has a Pareto distribution with parameters:

$\alpha = 4 + a + 0.1 \times b, \\ \theta=10+d+0.1\times e$

Find the kurtosis (round answer to 2 decimal places) of X.

---

**My steps**:
$f(x)=\frac{\alpha\theta^\alpha}{(x+\theta)^{\alpha+1}}=\frac{(4+a+0.1b)(10+d+0.1e)^{(4+a+0.1b)}}{(x+10+d+0.1e)^{(4+a+0.1b+1)}}$

$F(x)=1-(\frac{\theta}{x+\theta})^{\alpha}=1-(\frac{10+d+0.1e}{x+10+d+0.1e})^{(4+a+0.1b)}$

$E(X^k)=\frac{\theta^kk!}{(\alpha-1)...(\alpha-k)}$

$E(X)=\frac{10+d+0.1e}{\alpha-1}$

$E(X^2)=\frac{(10+d+0.1e)^22!}{(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}$

I think it might be:
$E(a)=\frac{1}{9}*(0+1+2+...9)=\frac{45}{9}$

$E(a)=E(b)=E(c)=E(d)=E(e)$

$\alpha=4+\frac{45}{9}+0.1*\frac{45}{9}=\frac{19}{2}$

$\theta=10+\frac{45}{9}+0.1\frac{45}{9}=\frac{31}{2}$

$E(X)=\frac{31/2}{(19/2)-1}=\frac{32}{17}$

$E(X^4)=\frac{(31/2)^4*4!}{((19/2)-1)((19/2)-2)((19/2)-3)((19/2)-4)}=607.83$

I am not sure how I should handle the value a,b,c,d,e. Should I treat them as a probability? If so, how am I going to get a value?

Comment: I think we are doing the same question. Just sub the a,b,c,d,e with the actual numbers in your own matric number. The professor just wants everybody to have a unique answer.

Comment: please add the self-study tag

Answer (score 1):

This is a straight-forward but laborious calculation.  There are a number of ways to do it, but a simple way is to derive the form of the raw moments, then the central moments, and then the kurtosis.

---

**Raw moments:** Letting $X \sim \text{Pareto}(x_m, \alpha)$, for all $\alpha > k$ we have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(X^k) 
&= \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} x^k \cdot \text{Pareto}(x|x_m,\alpha) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{x_m}^\infty x^k \cdot \alpha \cdot x_m^\alpha \cdot x^{-(\alpha+1)} \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \alpha \cdot x_m^\alpha \cdot \int \limits_{x_m}^\infty x^{-(\alpha-k+1)} \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \alpha \cdot x_m^\alpha \cdot  \Bigg[ - \frac{1}{\alpha-k} \cdot x^{-(\alpha-k)} \Bigg]_{x=x_m}^{x \rightarrow \infty} \\[6pt]
&= \alpha \cdot x_m^\alpha \cdot \Bigg[ \frac{1}{\alpha-k} \cdot x_m^{-(\alpha-k)} \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\alpha}{\alpha-k} \cdot x_m^k. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

More generally, the raw moments are:

$$\mathbb{E}(X^k) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-k} \cdot x_m^k & & \text{for } \alpha > k, \\[6pt]
\infty & & \text{for } \alpha \leqslant k. \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

---

**Central moments:** For $\alpha>k$ we can use the binomial expansion to obtain the central moment:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}((X-\mu)^k)
&= \sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i} (-\mu)^{k-i} \mathbb{E}(X^i) \\[6pt]
&= x_m^k \sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i} \Big( - \frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1} \Big)^{k-i} \Big( \frac{\alpha}{\alpha-i} \Big). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

For $k=2$ and $\alpha>2$ we have the variance:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{V}(X) = \mathbb{E}((X-\mu)^2) 
&= x_m^2 \Bigg[ \frac{\alpha^2}{(\alpha-1)^2} - \frac{2 \alpha^2}{(\alpha-1)^2} + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha-2} \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= x_m^2 \Bigg[ - \frac{\alpha^2}{(\alpha-1)^2} + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha-2} \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\alpha \cdot x_m^2}{(\alpha-1)^2 (\alpha-2)} \Bigg[ - \alpha (\alpha-2) + (\alpha-1)^2 \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\alpha \cdot x_m^2}{(\alpha-1)^2 (\alpha-2)} \Bigg[ (- \alpha^2 + 2 \alpha) + (\alpha^2 -2 \alpha + 1) \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\alpha \cdot x_m^2}{(\alpha-1)^2 (\alpha-2)} \Bigg[ (- \alpha^2 + 2 \alpha) + (\alpha^2 -2 \alpha + 1) \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\alpha \cdot x_m^2}{(\alpha-1)^2 (\alpha-2)}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

For $k=4$ and $\alpha>4$, with a substantial amount of algebra, we have the central moment:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}((X-\mu)^4) 
&= x_m^4 \Bigg[ \frac{\alpha^4}{(\alpha-1)^4} - \frac{4 \alpha^4}{(\alpha-1)^4} + \frac{6 \alpha^3}{(\alpha-1)^2 (\alpha-2)} - \frac{4 \alpha^2}{(\alpha-1) (\alpha-3)} + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha-4} \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= x_m^4 \Bigg[ - \frac{3 \alpha^4}{(\alpha-1)^4} + \frac{6 \alpha^3}{(\alpha-1)^2 (\alpha-2)} - \frac{4 \alpha^2}{(\alpha-1) (\alpha-3)} + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha-4} \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= x_m^4 \cdot \frac{\Bigg[ \begin{matrix}
-3 \alpha^4 (\alpha-2) (\alpha-3) (\alpha-4) + 6 \alpha^3 (\alpha-1)^2 (\alpha-3) (\alpha-4) \\
- 4 \alpha^2 (\alpha-1)^3 (\alpha-2) (\alpha-4) + \alpha (\alpha-1)^4 (\alpha-2) (\alpha-3) \end{matrix} \Bigg]}{(\alpha-1)^4 (\alpha-2) (\alpha-3) (\alpha-4)} \\[6pt]
&= \cdots \\[6pt]
&= \frac{3 \alpha (3 \alpha^2 +\alpha + 2) \cdot x_m^4}{(\alpha-1)^4 (\alpha-2) (\alpha-3) (\alpha-4)}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Thus, for $\alpha>4$ we have kurtosis:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\kappa 
= \frac{\mathbb{E}((X-\mu)^4)}{\mathbb{E}((X-\mu)^2)^2}
&= \frac{3 \alpha (3 \alpha^2 +\alpha + 2) \cdot x_m^4}{(\alpha-1)^4 (\alpha-2) (\alpha-3) (\alpha-4)} \bigg/ \frac{\alpha^2 \cdot x_m^4}{(\alpha-1)^4 (\alpha-2)^2} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{3 (3 \alpha^2 +\alpha + 2)}{(\alpha-3) (\alpha-4)} \bigg/ \frac{\alpha}{\alpha-2} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{3 (\alpha-2) (3 \alpha^2 +\alpha + 2)}{\alpha (\alpha-3) (\alpha-4)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{3 (3 \alpha^3 - 5 \alpha^2 - 4)}{\alpha (\alpha-3) (\alpha-4)}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

We also have the excess-kurtosis:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\kappa - 3 
&= \frac{3 (3 \alpha^3 - 5 \alpha^2 - 4) - 3 \alpha (\alpha-3) (\alpha-4)}{\alpha (\alpha-3) (\alpha-4)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{3 (3 \alpha^3 - 5 \alpha^2 - 4) - 3 (\alpha^3 - 7 \alpha^2 + 12 \alpha)}{\alpha (\alpha-3) (\alpha-4)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{3 (2 \alpha^3 + 2 \alpha^2 - 12 \alpha - 4)}{\alpha (\alpha-3) (\alpha-4)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{6 (\alpha^3 + \alpha^2 - 6 \alpha - 2)}{\alpha (\alpha-3) (\alpha-4)}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This gives you a general formula for the kurtosis (or excess-kurtosis) of a Pareto distribution.  You should now be able to substitute your particular expressions for the parameters and obtain the result that pplies to your particular case.  I will leave the latter as an exercise for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Moment Generating Function to obtain whatever moment you are interested in.

[Wikipedia MGF entry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function)

Comment: Not possible, as the Pareto distribution has no moment generating function. (The moments do no exist when $n \geq \alpha$.)